# "Error al ejecutar el query en BigQuery o cargar el archivo en Cloud Storage: ReferenceError: Cannot access 'stream' before initialization"

Tags: nodejs, google-cloud-functions

Estoy haciendo una función en cloud functions, válgame la redundancia, en la que crea un csv y lo sube a un bucket de cloud sotorage pero me sale el siguiente error

```
"Error al ejecutar el query en BigQuery o cargar el archivo en Cloud Storage: ReferenceError: Cannot access 'stream' before initialization"
```

El codigo es el siguiente

```
const { BigQuery } = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');
const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const fastcsv = require('fast-csv');
const stream = require('stream');

// Configura las credenciales y la conexión a BigQuery y Cloud Storage.
   const bigquery = new BigQuery();
   const storage = new Storage();

   // Reemplaza 'mi-bucket' con el nombre de tu bucket de Cloud Storage.
   const bucketName = 'gs://correos_aplicacion_cdp';

   exports.crearCSVyCargarEnStorage = async (event, context) => {
    try {
        // Define el SQL query que deseas ejecutar en BigQuery.
        const sqlQuery = `SELECT 
        ClienteUnico,EmailContratante,Telefono,Fecha_emision,fecha_evento,Tipo,Poliza
        FROM \`inter-cdp-prod-1.productos_digitales.signup_successful\`
        where Grupo = 'DIGITAL' and tipo in ( 'CocheSeguro','MedicoSeguro')`;

// Ejecuta el query en BigQuery.
const [rows] = await bigquery.query(sqlQuery);

// Crea un archivo CSV en memoria.
const csvData = [];
csvData.push(['ClienteUnico', 'EmailContratante', 'Telefono', 'Fecha_emision', 'fecha_evento', 'Tipo', 'Poliza']); // Agrega los encabezados del CSV

rows.forEach((row) => {
  csvData.push([row.ClienteUnico, row.EmailContratante, row.Telefono, row.Fecha_emision, row.fecha_evento, row.Tipo, row.Poliza]);
});

const csvStream = fastcsv.format({ headers: true });
const bufferStream = new stream.PassThrough();
bufferStream.pipe(csvStream);
csvData.forEach((data) => csvStream.write(data));
csvStream.end();

// Define el nombre del archivo CSV que se creará en Cloud Storage.
const fileName = 'exitosos.csv';

// Sube el archivo CSV al bucket de Cloud Storage.
const file = storage.bucket(bucketName).file(fileName);
bufferStream.pipe(file.createWriteStream())
  .on('error', (err) => {
    console.error(err);
  })
  .on('finish', () => {
    console.log(`Archivo CSV '${fileName}' cargado en Cloud Storage.`);
  });
  } catch (error) {
   console.error('Error al ejecutar el query en BigQuery:', error);
  }
 };
```

Intente inicializar antes como constante stream = ''  pero no funciono.

Comment: Tenes suficiente reputacion para saber como funciona el sitio.. no tenes que editar la pregunta con la respuesta, tenes que escribir una respuesta y explicar que pasaba....